# Lua table for loop, "for each x in..."

Tags: for-loop, lua, lua-table

```
blocks = {block1 = {}, block2 = {}}

blocks.block1.x = 1
blocks.block1.y = 2

blocks.block2.x = 3
blocks.block2.y = 4
```

I would like to print `x` and `y` for every item in the blocks table, something like

```
for b in blocks do
    print(b.x)
    print(b.y)
end
```

I know blocks ends up being a local variable this way, but I do not know any other way to explain.

Basically I want the output

```
>
1
2
3
4
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no expert, but can you try this?

```
for _, v in pairs(blocks) do
    print(v.x)
    print(v.y)
end
```

[Output](http://codepad.org/DinEZ2DN)

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Though it does not guarantee that the order shall always be same.